# ngx-intl-tel-input doesn't work with shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, shadow-dom

I'm trying to use ngx-intl-tel-input with shadow DOM by isn't works, I already test import styles manually but the select don't works I can't select another country.

My stackblitz test with shadow DOM:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-ng-12?file=src/app/app.component.ts